# No tests found, exiting with code 1, even if tests are found

Tags: javascript, typescript, testing, jestjs, ts-jest

I'm running `jest` command and got this output.

```bash
$ jest
No tests found, exiting with code 1
Run with `--passWithNoTests` to exit with code 0
In /Users/igormakowski/Documents/repositories/nestjs-template
  9 files checked.
  testMatch:  - 0 matches
  testPathIgnorePatterns: /Users/igormakowski/Documents/repositories/nestjs-template/node_modules/, /Users/igormakowski/Documents/repositories/nestjs-template/dist/, /Users/igormakowski/Documents/repositories/nestjs-template/.stryker-tmp/, .js - 0 matches
  testRegex: .*\.spec\.ts$ - 1 match
Pattern:  - 0 matches
error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

As you can see 1 test is found, but jest is not executing it anyway. I've got similar another project with pretty same config and everything works there.

`jest.config.ts`

```
import type { Config } from 'jest'

const configuration: Config = {
  moduleFileExtensions: ['js', 'json', 'ts'],
  rootDir: '.',
  testRegex: '.*\\.spec\\.ts$',
  // testMatch: ['<rootDir>/src/**/*.spec.ts'],
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.(t|j)s$': 'ts-jest',
  },
  verbose: true,
  collectCoverageFrom: ['**/*.(t|j)s'],
  testPathIgnorePatterns: [
    '<rootDir>/node_modules/',
    '<rootDir>/dist/',
    '<rootDir>/.stryker-tmp/',
    '.js',
  ],
  moduleNameMapper: {
    '^~/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src/$1',
    '^@modules/app(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src/modules/$1',
    '^@common/filters(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src/common/$1',
  },
  coveragePathIgnorePatterns: [
    '.*\\.(interface|module|schema|entity|dto|enum|d).ts',
    '.*\\.e2e-spec.ts',
    'index.ts',
    'main.ts',
  ],
  coverageDirectory: './coverage',
  testEnvironment: 'node',
  roots: ['<rootDir>/src'],
}

export default configuration
```

My environment:

```
System:
    OS: macOS 13.2.1
    CPU: (8) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-7820HQ CPU @ 2.90GHz
  Binaries:
    Node: 18.14.2 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v18.14.2/bin/node
    Yarn: 1.22.19 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v18.14.2/bin/yarn
    npm: 9.5.0 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v18.14.2/bin/npm
  npmPackages:
    jest: 29.5.0 => 29.5.0
```

Reproduction: https://github.com/Mnigos/nestjs-template

I tried newer version of jest(29.6.1): Tried to use testMatch instead of testRegex. Also tried to reinstall dependencies and reload vscode project and using jest flags like

```
jest --testMatch **/src/**/*.spec.ts
```

```
jest --config jest.config.ts
```

```
./node_modules/.bin/jest --config jest.config.ts
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When run jest with custom configuration file, you need use option `--config`.

```
jest --config jest.config.ts
```

See more at [here](https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration).

Edit: You need remove '.js' in `testPathIgnorePatterns`.

Comment: Jest is detecing config files anyway, but even with specifying configuration I got same result.

Comment: But I'm testing only typescript files. How is this suppose to help?

Comment: I don't really know base code of `testPathIgnorePatterns` in jest project. But this options should only contain list dir, if you try pass `.js` , i guess that jest think is 'rootDir'  like '.' . Because if you test or ignore some files you have option `testRegex`

Comment: I tried to remove `.js` from `testPathIgnorePatterns`, but still got same result.

Comment: Too magic, I just try clone your project from github, remove `.js` from `testPathIgnorePatterns`  in  `jest.config.ts` and run `jest` and it work.

Comment: Try use jest cli local: `./node_modules/.bin/jest --config jest.config.ts`

Comment: still same result.

Comment: Okay I'm not sure why but now I've deleted `.js` from `testPathIgnorePatterns` and it works. Thanks for help.